# Using Here3+ for GNSS information, missing documentation?

Tags: gps, drone, can, gnss

The Here3+ is a GNSS receiver often used by drones, specifically the pixhawk. I wanted to use this receiver in my own project for geopositioning, I am however completely unable to find any documentation on how to read its data. I have a CAN connection set up, but it doesn't send anything legible like when using NMEA. And I really don't want to try reverse engineering it by observing what the pixhawk and the Here3+ communicate with eachother. Am I just bad at google? What steps should I take to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The Here3+ uses the DroneCAN/uavCAN protocol that is now renamed to [cyphal](https://opencyphal.org/#what). This is an entirely different protocol from NMEA2000. The CAN msgs build-up is done by [DSDL](https://legacy.uavcan.org/Specification/3._Data_structure_description_language/) description. With DSDL file (see [example](https://github.com/dronecan/DSDL/blob/master/dronecan/remoteid/20031.Location.uavcan) c-code can be generated with specific [webtool](https://nunaweb.opencyphal.org/#/#/#/#/).
Another possibility is to read the canbus with the [DroneCAN GUI](https://dronecan.github.io/GUI_Tool/Overview/). The translation is done in the tool.
It is a bit strange that a dbc-file isn't used...

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

*After having watched [Here 3+ CAN GPS For Ardupilot & PX4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYH0y8RrQUU), and even though the Here3/3+ **does** indeed contain a NEO-M8P-2, it became clear that the presence of the STM32F302/STM32H757, and the fact that the Here3+ has **only** CAN connectors, means that the serial connection can not be used and configuration of the u-blox component using u-center is not possible. Therefore, the suggestions offered below, unfortunately, no longer apply.*

---

There is a manual, [Here 3 manual](https://docs.cubepilot.org/user-guides/here-3/here-3-manual), which doesn't *seem* to delve into the communication protocol.

This page, [HEX/ProfiCNC Here+ RTK GPS](https://docs.px4.io/v1.11/en/gps_compass/rtk_gps_hex_hereplus.html), looks a bit more promising. It states that the Here 3 uses the I2C protocol and that it is based upon the [u-blox NEO M8P](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/neo-m8p-series).

Therefore, as a starting point at least, it would seem logical to just use the various datasheets (and online tutorials) for the U-Blox Neo M8P, in order to figure out how to communicate with the Here 3 - assuming, that is, that they are functionally equivalent.

Finally, assuming that the HERE 3 *is* functionally similar to a NEO M8P, you could try hooking your HERE 3 up (via USB, using an FTDI interface, if necessary) to **[u-center](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/u-center)** (running on a Windows PC) and configure it there.

For reference I found that these two videos were invaluable:

- [10Hz U-blox binary GPS data in 66 lines of code (arduino)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwhCX0c8Xe0&list=RDCMUCTXOorupCLqqQifs2jbz7rQ&start_radio=1&rv=TwhCX0c8Xe0&t=195)
- [UBX binary protocol, extra tips (arduino)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylxwOg2pXrc)

However, they do just use the UART/serial interface and only cover the UBX protocol and ***not*** the CAN and NMEA that you require. That said, they should give you an insight to getting the NMEA messages/packets working correctly.

These two videos cover too much information to summarise here, in this answer, unfortunately. Although, I did make some rough notes on (full disclosure) my blog page, [More GPS](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2023/06/13/more-gps/).

This Wiki page may also be useful: [Sensors/GPS](https://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Sensors/GPS).